# tf.get_default_graph does not remove nodes

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the following code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    x = tf.Variable(3, name="x")
    x.graph is tf.get_default_graph()  #prints True
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    x.graph is tf.get_default_graph()  #prints False
    x                                  #prints <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why does the node x exist after I did the reset?
2. Node x does not exist in the default graph. Where does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

1. The node does not exist in the current default graph. prining `x` just outputs the python variable that you defined. The variable exists in python, but the current default graph does not contain it.
2. The only thing that exists is the `x` python variable. You can verify this running the following script.

This script throws a `ValueError` exception:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(3, name="x")
x.graph is tf.get_default_graph()  #prints True
tf.reset_default_graph()
x.graph is tf.get_default_graph()  #prints False

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) # initialize the variables
    sess.run(x) #error
```

> Tensor Tensor("x:0", shape=(), dtype=int32_ref) is not an element of this graph.